# Особенности привязки RelativeSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть окно, которое содержит следующую `XAML`-разметку:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Button Background="Aquamarine"
                                        Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TestData}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Content"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TestData}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>

    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Command="{Binding DoCommand}"
            Content="Тыц" />
</Grid>
```

В этом окне элемент `ContentControl` содержит два `DataTrigger`'a, которые в зависимости от значения свойства `Value` устанавливают различное значение свойству `Content` элемента `ContentControl`. В первом  случае, в качестве значения устанавливается элемент `Button`,  во втором - `простой текст`, который берется из свойства `TestData`.

Как можно заметить в элементе `Button` присутствует привязка на свойство `TestData`, расположенное во `ViewModel`, и задается она следующим образом:

```
<Button Background="Aquamarine" 
        Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TestData}" />
```

т.е. при конфигурации `Binding` используется свойство `RelativeSource`, позволяющее задать источник привязки относительно текущего объекта. Проблема заключается в том, что по какой-то причине, текущая конфигурация `Binding` для кнопки не работает, т.е., привязка к свойству `TestData` не происходит.

При этом, аналогичная привязка, в которой задается простой текст отрабатывает успешно.

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TestData}" />
```

Кроме того, если переписать `Binding` для кнопки иначе:

```
<Button Background="Aquamarine" Content="{Binding TestData}" />
```

то все заработает отлично.

Хотелось бы разобраться в особенности такого поведения, почему привязка в кнопке заданная с использованием `RelativeSource` не работает, а простой `Binding` наоборот?

Comment: А если так: https://pastebin.com/VCuXw1BN?

Comment: @VladD, этот вариант решения работает, но кабы сказать, я не ищу альтернативных способов решения проблемы, а пытаюсь докопаться до истины и понять детали ) Т.е. почему привязка у кнопки заданная с использованием `RelativeSource` не работает, что там за магия происходит внутри? Казалось бы, кнопка в визуальном дереве  присутствует так в чем тогда проблема взять и найти ее родителя `Window` и привязаться к свойству из его `DataContext`.

Comment: Ну, думаю, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь вставить контрол в виде контента не через шаблон.

Comment: @VladD просто как-то странно получается, привязка `Content="{Binding TestData}"` в кнопке работает, я ожидал аналогично поведения при использовании `RelativeSource`. По факту ведь эти привязки задают одно и тоже просто разными способами или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что так работать не должно, и то, что работает с другой привязкой — случайность. UI-элементы размножать можно только через template, иначе возможны сюрпризы (но именно _возможны_, а не _обязательно будет исключение_).

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вариант с биндингом кнопки не отрабатывает потому, что по факту во время срабатывания триггера она еще не помещена в визуальное дерево. Поэтому и не может найти предка и позаимствовать его датаконтекст. Если Вы работаете в Visual Studio, то открыв окно Output скорее всего увидите оповещение об ошибке подобного рода.

В случае же, где вы просто биндите контент уже существующего контентконтрола к тому же свойству всё работает, и это логично, потому что сам контент контрол уже помещен в визуальное дерево, соответственно может найти и заданого предка. 
Биндинг без RelativeSource отрабатывает потому, что он обращается напрямую к датаконтексту контейнера, в который помещен.